# GridView issue with large data while scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

I am having problem with "GridView".If I use 6  items then it is not creating problem while scrolling but as I increase no. of items its behavior is unpredictable.
Please check the following video link for better understanding my problem:
[GridView Issues video link](https://mega.nz/#!PhYjySoD!olXomEH5DSkXuPT9Z_cjYMhD7euqJqe1eCk7UvZ9Tuo)

I am attaching my codes here:

1. activity_achievements.xml

   ```
           <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:id="@+id/header"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="60dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:background="@color/green_color">

                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_iv"
                       android:text="Acheivements"
                       android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                       android:textSize="24sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold" />

                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/back_iv"
                       android:layout_width="25dp"
                       android:layout_height="25dp"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                       android:src="@drawable/back" />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/total_achievements_tv"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                       android:text="0/15"
                       android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                       android:textSize="24sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold" />
               </RelativeLayout>

               <GridView
                   android:id="@+id/acheivements_gv"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                   android:columnWidth="90dp"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                   android:numColumns="2"
                   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                   android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
           </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. achievements_row.xml

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <com.xyz.quitsmoking.view.AchievementsView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:gravity="center">

               <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                   android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/card_view1"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                   android:background="@color/white_color"
                   card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:orientation="vertical">

                       <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/image_iv"
                           android:layout_width="100dp"
                           android:layout_height="100dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:layout_margin="10dp"
                           android:src="@drawable/achievement" />
                       <TextView
                           android:id="@+id/title_tv"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:textSize="20sp"
                           android:padding="10dp"
                           android:text="Himalyi"
                           android:textColor="@color/green_color" />
                       <TextView
                           android:id="@+id/desc_tv"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="match_parent"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:textSize="16sp"
                           android:padding="10dp"
                           android:text="5 cigarettes non-smoked"
                           android:textColor="@color/teal_color" />
                   </LinearLayout>
               </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
           </pairroxz.com.quitsmoking.view.AchievementsView>
   ```
3. AchievementsAdapter.java

   ```
           public class AchievementsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
               private Context context;
               private ArrayList<Achievements> list;
               private LayoutInflater inflater;

               public AchievementsAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Achievements> list){
                   this.context = context;
                   this.list = list;
                   initialize();
               }

               private void initialize() {
                   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
               }

               @Override
               public int getCount() {
                   return list.size();
               }

               @Override
               public Object getItem(int position) {
                   return position;
               }

               @Override
               public long getItemId(int position) {
                   return position;
               }

               @Override
               public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                   AchievementsView view = null;
                   if(view==null) {
                       view = (AchievementsView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievements_row,null);
                   }else{
                       view = (AchievementsView) convertView;
                   }
                   view.setContents(list.get(position));
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                   return view;
               }

           }
   ```
4. AchievementsView.java

   ```
           public class AchievementsView extends RelativeLayout {
               private TextView title_tv,desc_tv;
               private ImageView image_iv;


               public AchievementsView(Context context) {
                   super(context);
               }

               public AchievementsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                   super(context, attrs);
               }

               public AchievementsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                   super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
               }

               @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
               public AchievementsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
                   super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
               }

               @Override
               protected void onFinishInflate() {
                   super.onFinishInflate();
                   initialize();
               }

               private void initialize() {
                  image_iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_iv);
                  title_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
                  desc_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc_tv);
               }

               public void setContents(Achievements achievements){
                   image_iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(achievements.getImg()));
                   title_tv.setText(achievements.getTitle());
                   desc_tv.setText(achievements.getDesc());
               }
           }
   ```
5. AchievementsActivity.java

   ```
           public class AchievementsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

               private GridView achievements_gv;
               private AchievementsAdapter adapter;
               private ArrayList<Achievements> list;
               DatabaseHelper helper;
               private ImageView back_iv;

               @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_achievements);
                   initialize();
               }

               private void initialize() {
                   helper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
                   back_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_iv);
                   achievements_gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.acheivements_gv);
                   list = new ArrayList<Achievements>();
                   getData();
                   setListener();
               }

               private void setListener() {
                   back_iv.setOnClickListener(this);
               }



               private void getData() {
                  list = helper.getAchievementsList();
                   //list =
                   adapter = new AchievementsAdapter(this, list);
                   achievements_gv.setAdapter(adapter);
               }

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   switch (v.getId()) {
                       case R.id.back_iv:
                           onBackPressed();
                           break;
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more info than that. Layout of each row, adapter code, etc.

Comment: This should be an issue of reusing cells/grid items, the reason why you're getting the first 6 is right is because those are the items visible on screen at first time of load, after that Android re-use the items and update the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(view == null) 
view.setTag(viewHolder);
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```

don't use this. or send your code